# Adding a subview to the top of a scroll view for iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiscrollview, subview

I have a toggle that turns on and off a subview for an audio player. When it is toggled on, I want the player to appear at the top of the scroll view. When it is toggled off, I want the scroll view to return to the state it was previously in (without the audio player).

Comment: Should this "player" scroll with the scrollview or should it be static and stick to the top of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you meant but, You can just set your subview's position before unhiding it in scroll view !

Comment: I am using that approach, but the issue I am having is that the scroll view is being cut off at the bottom.

Comment: Looking for `[yourScrollView scrollToTop]` ?

Comment: What does that do exactly?

Comment: It scrolls your scrollView to top. If you have put your subview there, you can scroll using this method to top so that it get visible. You can also scroll back using `[yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect) animated:(BOOL)]`. Was that what you were looking for ?

Comment: To clarify, I want to put a subview on the top of the scroll view. So I want to shift the scroll view down by the height of the sub view.

Comment: That's easy, you just have to set theScrollView's position in addition to setting the subview's position. Any code needed ?

Comment: `CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height);

    [yourScrollView setFrame:newFrame];`

Answer (score 0):

looking for sendsubviewtoback / bringsubviewtofront ?!